# How can I convert an EBNF grammar to Javacc?

Tags: javacc

I want to implement an interpreter for a multi notation (prefix, infix, and postfix) arithmetic language. Its grammar description in EBNF is given below. How can I code this in Javacc?

```
< Process> --> PROCESS  id ; <First Section> <SecondSection>
<First Section> --> VARIABLES [<Variable List>];
<First List> --> <First Def> | <First Def>, <First List>
<First Def> --> <First Name> [ EQUAL integer_literal ]
<First Name> --> id

<Second Section> --> COMMANDS {<Statement>;}
<Statement> --> <Input Statement> | <Output Statement> | <Assignment Statement>

<Input Statement> --> READ 'message ' <First Name>
<Output Statement> --> WRITE 'message ' [ <Expression>]
<Assignment Statement> --> <First Name> <-- <Expression>

<Expression> --> <PrefixExp> | <InfixExp> | <PostfixExp>

<InfixExp> --> <Term> | <InfixExp> (PLUS | MINUS) <Term>
<Term> --> <Factor> | <Term> (MULTIPLICATION | DIVISION) <Factor>
<Factor> --> integer_literal | <First Name> | ( <InfixExp> )

<PrefixExp> --> <Operator> <PrefixExp> <PrefixExp>
<PrefixExp> --> integer_literal | <First Name>

<PostfixExp> --> <PostfixExp> <PostfixExp> <Operator>
<PostfixExp> --> integer_literal | <First Name>

<Operator> --> (ADD | SUBSTRACT | MULTIPLY | DIVIDE)
```

Comment: You can read JavaCC documentation and examples and start coding ;)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "How can I coding this with Javacc?"?

Comment: I want to coding this grammar with javacc language. I read too many documents about Javacc but I don't exactly understand. I'm new in Javacc. I want to coded tihs grammar with Javacc and then if I coded this I wirte main class and test code. I mean I write arithmetic language like this. I started to coding, I wrote tokens but I didn't implement grammar to javacc. Are you suggest any good and simple site about Javacc code example about this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it!  Your grammar, as it stands, is ambiguous. First rewrite the grammar in EBNF form to an unambiguous and non-left-recursive form. After you have done that, it will be ready to convert to JavaCC.

For example, consider a command

```
write 'hello' 1
```

is the 1 a prefix expression, a postfix expression, or an infix expression?  Your grammar permits all three interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

For starters:

- Read the [JavaCC FAQ](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-FAQ/).
- Browse through the existing JavaCC Grammars [here](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/javacc.html) or [here](https://java.net/projects/javacc/downloads/directory/contrib/grammars).
- Take one and try to gradually build your grammar based on it.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend reading the whole FAQ as a starting point, but there it does contain a list of tutorials, which would be a good place to start. Also read the documentation at https://javacc.java.net/doc/ .